# SQL Distinct Query

Tags: sql

My SQL seems to be letting me down this morning. I have a table with the columns

```
Id, Guid,AttributeId,AttributeValue,CreationDate,Status
```

This stores data from a qustonnaire which has around 15 pages to it. Each time you move on to the next question (next page) in the questionnaire the entire questionnaire is persisted to the table i.e after completing the 1st question, that questions data is stored in the table, after completing the 2nd question, the 1st and 2nd question is persisted to the table meaning that know, we have two lots of the 1st qestion and one lot of the second question saved in the table.

I need to write a query that will return the latest lot of saved data for a given questionnaire (and all questionnaires). i.e. if the user got to question 13 i would want only that set of data returned.

Comment: Could you rephrase your requirements in English, please?  :p

Comment: Is the CreationDate column updated to the table.. if so you can just do an Order by Creation Date Desc and you should have the latest question.

Comment: Assuming `Id` is a surrogate key, what is `Guid`?

Comment: Please give example of input data and expected output.

Comment: Which value contains the question no? Do you have any sql example to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you notice that in the table you mentioned there is no QuestionNumber nor QuestionResult field.  So, where is that data stored?

Comment: Guid is the unique Questionnaire id. CreationDate is inserted when the questionnaire gets inserted (after each question is completed) and AttributeId and Value are the answers to the questions (it's denormalised).

Comment: If I've just completed question 13, what uniquely idenfies those 13 answers - is it the guid?

Comment: The combination of the Guid and the CreationDate

Comment: Is the lot of questions saved with the same creation date? If not, is there any way to identify the question number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
SELECT Q.*
FROM Questionnaire Q
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TOP 1 Guid, CreationDate
  FROM Questionnaire
  ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
) Q2
ON Q2.Guid = Q.Guid AND Q2.CreationDate = Q.CreationDate
```

...ought to do it.  The join to Guid is possibly redundant - and you'll presumably need a WHERE somewhere to ensure you get *the* questionnaire for the particular user / session.

Comment: @Thanks Will, thats done the trick nicely. I definitely haven't got my SQL hat on this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does the trick...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Questionaire ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

Comment: The data is denormalised, so it needs to return the latest set of data (unkown amount of rows)